# sleep(duration) vs Future.delayed(duration)

Tags: flutter, dart, state

What is the difference btw the two of them (sleep vs Future.delayed)? What's going on behind the scenes in both scenarios?

I don't understand the different outcomes in the following examples.

**Future.delayed:** does what I'd expect it to do:

1. setState rebuilds the widget and colors the rectangle in black color
2. Then it waits 10 seconds

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:io';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      Color appColor = Colors.green;

      changeColors() async {
        setState(() {
          appColor = Color(0xff000000);
        });
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
        print('after 10 seconds');
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(height: 100, width: 100, color: appColor),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => changeColors(),
                      child: Text('click me'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**sleep:** does NOT do what I'd expect it to do:

1. setState does NOT rebuild the widget tree once I change the appColor to black. Why not?
2. It waits 10 seconds
3. Then out of nowhere, the widget tree is being rebuilt and color of the rectangle turns black: Why?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:io';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      Color appColor = Colors.green;

      changeColors() {
        setState(() {
          appColor = Color(0xff000000);
        });

        sleep(Duration(seconds:10));
        print('after 10 seconds');
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(height: 100, width: 100, color: appColor),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => changeColors(),
                      child: Text('click me'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: hmm... so weird. I just tried my original example on a diff computer and suddenly both examples act the same way (when looking at the window). The only diff is in the console since sleep is throwing some errors. How is that possible? Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sleep`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/sleep.html) pauses execution in the Dart isolate for the specified amount of time.  Nothing will happen during that time.

`Future.delayed` *schedules* an operation to occur at some point in the future.  It is asynchronous, and other operations can occur in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that didn't quite answer my question. In my sleep example, why didn't the setState function rebuild the widget tree and then paused the execution in the Dart isolate? setState should have been executed before sleep came in, right?

Comment: @TomasBaran `setState` does update the state immediately, but by pausing execution, you don't allow the widget tree to rebuild and draw a new frame.

Comment: hmm... so weird. I just tried my original example on a diff computer and suddenly both examples act the same way (when looking at the window). The only diff is in the console since sleep is throwing some errors.